# Tensorflow Python LSTM Understanding multiple Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

so I am new with machine learning and I got a bonus course at my university where I have to train a lstm model to generate captions. I have read this so far: [Blogpost_about_lstms](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

And used this as reference: [some_random_code](https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/lstm_tutorial.py)

So what I want to achieve:
I have an Dataset which is structured like this:
output from an CNN with a Vector on size 2048 that holds some "features" of an image. And 5 Captions describing that image.

Training:
input: CNN vector + Captions
output: Caption (guess)

Validation:
input: CNN vector
output: caption (guess)

So how can I use 2 Inputs (the CNN data and a Caption Sequence) to train to generate new captions only from an CNN input vector!

This is kinda tricky and I cannot grasp the theory in this. And Tensorflow is also quite a thing I have to say.

I have a normal Seq_2_Seq model in place that works. But now I am stuck :/

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, _input, is_training, hidden_size, vocab_size, num_layers,
                dropout=config.trainer.dropout, init_scale=config.trainer.init_scale):
        self.is_training = is_training
        self.input_obj = _input
        self.batch_size = _input.batch_size
        self.num_steps = _input.num_steps
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        # create the word embeddings
        with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
            randomized = tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, hidden_size], -init_scale, init_scale)
            print("randomized: ", randomized)
            embedding = tf.Variable(randomized)
            inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.input_obj.input_data)

        if is_training and dropout < 1:
            inputs = tf.nn.dropout(inputs, dropout)



        # set up the state storage / extraction
        self.init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_layers, 2, self.batch_size, hidden_size])

        state_per_layer_list = tf.unstack(self.init_state, axis=0)
        rnn_tuple_state = tuple([tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list[idx][0], state_per_layer_list[idx][1])for idx in range(num_layers)])

        # create an LSTM cell to be unrolled
        print("Hidden size: ", hidden_size)
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=config.trainer.forget_bias)
        # add a dropout wrapper if training
        if is_training and dropout < 1:
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=dropout)

        if num_layers > 1:
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

        print("input: ", inputs)
        output, self.state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)

        # reshape to (batch_size * num_steps, hidden_size)
        output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, hidden_size])

        softmax_w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([hidden_size, vocab_size], -init_scale, init_scale))
        softmax_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size], -init_scale, init_scale))
        logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(output, softmax_w, softmax_b)

        # Reshape logits to be a 3-D tensor for sequence loss
        logits = tf.reshape(logits, [self.batch_size, self.num_steps, vocab_size])

        # Use the contrib sequence loss and average over the batches
        loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits,
                                                self.input_obj.targets,
                                                tf.ones([self.batch_size, self.num_steps], dtype=tf.float32),
                                                average_across_timesteps=False,
                                                average_across_batch=True)
        # Update the cost
        self.cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss)

        # get the prediction accuracy
        self.softmax_out = tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(logits, [-1, vocab_size]))
        self.predict = tf.cast(tf.argmax(self.softmax_out, axis=1), tf.int32)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(self.predict, tf.reshape(self.input_obj.targets, [-1]))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

        if not is_training:
            return
        self.learning_rate = tf.Variable(0.01, trainable=False)

        tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
        grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars), 5)
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
        self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars),
                                                global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step())

        self.new_lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
        self.lr_update = tf.assign(self.learning_rate, self.new_lr)

    def assign_lr(self, session, lr_value):
        session.run(self.lr_update, feed_dict={self.new_lr: lr_value})
```

I don't need a solution but some explanation how to move forward would be awesome!!

Comment: Is it mandatory that the LSTM input is the CNN output? I know of image-to-caption decoders that do not operate on the CNN output but rather simply condition on it.

Comment: Nono maybe I said something wrong
training:
input: CNN vector + Captions
output: Caption (guess)

Validation:
input: CNN vector
output: caption (guess)